# ngbCollapse for child components on a loop

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm using `ng-bootstrap` to add some directives for my Angular 4 app. Right now I'm trying to implement a sidebar with links, which are populated dynamically. I have a group of parent links that will expand on click and show a group of other links (fragments within the page). This is what I have, based on the example found on the page:

### Template:

```
<ul *ngFor="let category of categories" class="nav flex-column">
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" routerLink="./" (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed"
     [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed">{{category[0].name}}</a>
  <ul class="nav flex-column">
    <div id="questions{{category[0].id}}" [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed">
      <li *ngFor="let question of category[1]" class="nav-item">
        <a class="question-item" routerLink="./" fragment="question{{question.id}}">{{question.name}}</a>
      </li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

### Code:

```
export class QuestionListComponent implements OnInit {
    public isCollapsed = true;
    private categoryQuestions: Array<[Category, Question[]]>;
    /* ... */
}
```

Some things are initialized on `ngOnInit()` but that's not the main focus. Right now this works in the sense that the parent categories are collapsed on page load, but clicking on a single one expands all the other child components. My question would be: How do I access the `[ngbCollapse]` property for each `category` so I can modify it on the `(click)` event? I can modify anything from the template. I did notice that ngbCollapse only works on `<div>` on the version I'm using ("@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.26")

### Update:

Someone suggested I did my own directive based on the [original one.](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/collapse/collapse.ts) Still, I'm not seeing how the state shouldn't be shared among the groups.

```
<ul *ngFor="let categoryQuestion of categoryQuestions" class="nav flex-column">
<li class="nav-item">
  <button class="btn btn-link" [appQuestionCollapser]="categoryQuestion[0].id"
      [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed">{{categoryQuestion[0].name}}</button>
  <ul class="nav flex-column">
    <div id="questions{{categoryQuestion[0].id}}" class="collapse">
      <li *ngFor="let question of categoryQuestion[1]" class="nav-item">
        <a class="question-item" routerLink="./" fragment="question{{question.id}}">{{question.name}}</a>
      </li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</li>
```

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appQuestionCollapser]'
})
export class QuestionCollapserDirective {

  @Input('appQuestionCollapser') categoryId: number;
  public collapsed: boolean;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { this.collapsed = true; }

  @HostListener('click') onCategoryClick() {
     this.el.nativeElement.className += ' active';
     const element = document.querySelector('#questions' + this.categoryId);
     if (this.collapsed) {
       element.classList.add('show');
     } else {
       element.classList.remove('show');
   }
   this.collapsed = !this.collapsed;
 }
}
```

Besides, sometimes out of the blue I get the error `Can't bind to 'appQuestionCollapser' since it isn't a known property of 'button'.("yQuestions" class="nav flex-column"> <li class="nav-item"> <button class="btn btn-link" [ERROR ->][appQuestionCollapser]="categoryQuestion[0].id"`. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add simple version of `categoryQuestions` array? Why do you use `category[0]` and `category[1]`?

Comment: Seems i got it :)

Comment: It's an array of tuples... I know, a bit complicated.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/waC6CudnvmiORAMs517e?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to change the input on the template. Using an anchor tag is fine.

```
<ul *ngFor="let categoryQuestion of categoryQuestions" class="nav flex-column">
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="btn btn-link" appQuestionCollapser="{{categoryQuestion[0].id}}" routerLink="./">{{categoryQuestion[0].name}}</a>
  <ul class="nav flex-column">
    <div id="questions{{categoryQuestion[0].id}}" class="collapse">
      <li *ngFor="let question of categoryQuestion[1]" class="nav-item">
        <a class="question-item" routerLink="./" fragment="question{{question.id}}">{{question.name}}</a>
      </li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```